# Create SAPUI5 XML Chat Dialog

Tags: sapui5

I want to create the chat dialog but without popover and I am totally have no idea. How do I achieve that?
I found one great example from SAP blog: https://blogs.sap.com/2018/07/05/implementing-a-chatbot-custom-control. But I want to implement it without pop-over, basically I want to have a chat dialog box on the flat panel.

Comment: Replace `_popover` aggregation with other containers that suit you.

Comment: Thanks. any working example ?

Comment: @Binh, unfortunately just replacing `_popover` would not work since the code has lines that accesses specifically a popover's properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you read through the [blog post](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/07/05/implementing-a-chatbot-custom-control), in the **User Input...** section, it says,

> the chat dialog is simply a sap.m.List (without separators between the FedListItems used)  and also a sap.m.FeedInput where the end user
>   will write.

Therefore can check the `sap.m.FeedInput` control to achieve something similar. It enables adding "feeds" and display it in a `sap.m.List` control using the `sap.m.FeedListItem`

[Feed Input demo](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.Feed/preview)

[Feed Input documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.FeedInput)

[Feed List Item documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.FeedListItem)